# an Easy Angular code not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new in Angular.js, I am watching pluralsight Angular tutorial, I did what the teacher told on that videos:

```
<!Doctype>
<html lang="en" ng-app>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 ng-controller="helloWorldCtrl">{{helloMessage}}</h1>

        <script href="angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function helloWorldCtrl ($scope) {
                $scope.helloMessage = "Hello World!";
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The h1 should be `Hello World!` but it is `{{helloMessage}}`

I am using Latest version of Firefox on windows8 with latest version of Angular

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! Getting any errors in the console? Can you post a reference to whatever you are reading?

Comment: @noa No error in console and firebug

Comment: There can be any number of reasons. Whenever posting questions related to browser + javascript it is always advisable to include console error. For your issue, what is the angular version. Latest version disable global controller like you have created? Where is ng-app?

Comment: version of angular ?

Comment: @Chandermani please see the question again

Comment: right click the page and hit view source. Then click on your angular.min.js link. does it work?

Comment: @YangLi yes of course it is working and I can see the code

Comment: @Lash Global controllers are not allowed above version 1.2.0 https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!Doctype>
<html lang="en" ng-app>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 ng-controller="helloWorldCtrl">{{helloMessage}}</h1>

        <script href="angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function helloWorldCtrl ($scope) {
                $scope.helloMessage = "Hello World!";
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Above code works without any issue so it is clear whatever problem is with your version issue. Use nuget to resolve the issue in case you are using Visual studio.

Comment: Do you mean I just change the script to above?

Comment: I did not changed any thing except having script tag added

Answer (score 0):

The syntax has changed, you have to add ng-app to the body part, and change the script src, the following code works.

```
    <body ng-app>
        <h1 ng-controller="helloWorldCtrl">{{helloMessage}}</h1>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function helloWorldCtrl ($scope) {

                $scope.helloMessage = "Hello World!";
            }
        </script>
    </body>
```

Comment: <body ng-app>                                                                                        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

You should a module in your script.
Hope the following code helps you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.12">  </script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
   <h1 ng-controller="MainCtrl">Hello {{name}}!</h1>

    <script>      
      var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

      app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.name = 'World';
      });   
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4wPCKluABnTGHux5BBFT?p=preview):-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="one">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.4.0-beta.3" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-beta.3/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

<body>
        <h1 ng-controller="helloWorldCtrl">{{helloMessage}}</h1>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var app=angular.module("one",[]);
        app.controller("helloWorldCtrl",function  ($scope) {
                $scope.helloMessage = "Hello World!";
            });

        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

I assume there is version problem if you are using new version of angular above 1.2.0 it is not allowed to use global controller in that version [Source](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration)